# Sublime Text 2: View working directory/directory of file

Tags: text, editor, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I think it would be nice to have the directory show up in the bottom status bar of the window. I can't find any sort of file info from the menu, so if I have the same file with the same name opened from two different directories, there's no way for me to tell which one I'm currently editing!

Comment: There's a thread about this on the ST2 UserEcho.

Comment: @ybakos thanks, I saw this. But really the tab-hover takes care of the "issue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that hovering over a tab in this editor will display its path. This is quite sufficient for me (though having it always visible at the bottom would still be awesome!).

I have created a plugin to display the path of the currently opened view in the status bar. This helps when the window is in full-screen mode where you will not see the file path in the title bar (It never shows that for OS X anyway).

Comment: I'm not totally happy with it because the path field doesn't show up in the statusbar always in the same position, and i am not confident that the package manager install out of the box works on ST3, but the plugin is called SublimeStatusbarPath. On ST2 it should work from Package Manager. If on ST3 you can clone the repo in your Plugins folder. Here is the [github link](https://github.com/unphased/SublimeStatusbarPath)

Answer (score 3):

You can make sublime text to show the full path of the current file in the title bar by changing some settings in the preferences.

If you are on OS X add

> "show_full_path":true,

to your user settings and check the same for the default settings.

On other system's it's there by default I guess, but you can always make sure. Hope this helps.